# How to create an oblong ion-fab-button with width set automatically according to content?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3, ionic4

Currently I am using the `ion-fab-button` as this:

```html
<ion-fab-button size="small" [ngClass]="{'active-tab': currentTab === 'bookmarks'}">
   <ion-icon name="bookmark-outline"></ion-icon>
   <ion-text>Bookmarks</ion-text>
</ion-fab-button>
```

To display the following,

[image]

I had to explicitly dictate the width of the `ion-fab-button` and override `--border-radius` to achieve the oblong shape (aka the racetrack shape, not oval).

```
element.style {
   --border-radius: 20px;
   max-width: unset;
   min-width: unset;
   width: 120px;
}
```

I tried playing around with the other attributes. Like trying out `display: inline-block` and such. But I can't seem to figure it out.

How would you do it on your end to achieve the same thing without assigning a specific width? Since the labels (in the `ion-text`) length will vary, I need the width to be dynamic.

Comment: Have you found any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible using the *ion-fab-button*. This element contains a span with the class *button-inner* which sets position absolute to the content, and the span can't be styled as far as I know since it's in the shadow-dom and does not have the *part* attribute.